# Is it possible to use images of different sizes in a Caffe network?

Tags: caffe

I'm researching anomaly detection recently. I have received a dataset with images of various sizes and ratios. I have learned that almost all Caffe networks need input of images of the same size, or of the same ratio so it can be easily resized. However my dataset contains anomalies of round shapes, linear shapes and irregular shapes, and all images have been cropped to fit the shape of each anomaly. It is impossible to resize this dataset. What should I do? Is it possible to use images of different sizes as input?

Comment: I don't understand how it is "impossible to resize this data set".  What format are these images that resizing is impossible, but that the images are still useful to Caffe?  You could perhaps pad the images to the same maximum size, but a Caffe model requires the input to be of consistent size and format.

Comment: What do you mean by "pad"? If one image is 200*200 and another is 100*500, and both of them are preprocessed so that they contain no more and no less than the anomalies themselves, how to process them without losing information or being distorted?

Comment: Add neutral pixels to each image until they're all 200*500.